# $m$-adic completion of the field of fraction

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, filtered-modules

Let $D$ be a domain and $K$ be its field of fraction. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we know that $\{m^nK \}$ is the $m$-adic filtration on $K$. But I think $m^nK=K$. Am I right? I do not understand  what the $m $-adic completion of $K $ is. Is there any informative  refrences for more informaion for this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I assume $m$ is an ideal of $D$ (is that what you meant?). If $m\neq 0$, then as you say, $m^nK=K$ and thus the $m$-adic completion of $K$ is zero.

Comment: Maybe what is meant is the field of fraction of the $m$-adic completion  of $D$ (assuming the latter is still a domain which requires some hypothesis) ?

Comment: Where did you see the phrase "$m$-adic completion of $K$"?

Comment: It is writen in  the paragraph 2 in page 56 of the book " integran-valued polynomals ".